# RDS SQL Server - how to create a schema - User does not have permission to perform this action

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services

I created MS SQL Server on RDS and am a newbie.

When I try and create a schema..

```
create schema test

19:27:36  [CREATE - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 15247, SQL State: S0001]  
User does not have permission to perform this action.
    ... 1 statement(s) executed, 0 row(s) affected, exec/fetch time: 0.000/0.000 sec  [0 successful, 0 warnings, 1 errors]
```

What does have to do to create a schema?  How do I edit the permissions?

How do I run as administrator?  In rds I created a user called root.

Comment: [Permissions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189462.aspx)

Comment: I know the RDS is a slightly different beast, but what does `select IS_SRVROLEMEMBER('sysadmin')` return when you run it? Also, what database are you running this in?

Answer (score 2):

AWS RDS restricts permissions on the `master` database, so you can't create schemas, roles, users, or logins there.

You need to create a second database, which will then allow you to create a schema as expected:

```
-- use the master database to create your new database:
USE master;  
CREATE DATABASE db_test;

-- then, use your new database to create your schema:
USE db_test;
CREATE SCHEMA yourschema;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run the auto-create script to create the database, You must add this property to ProSource item:

```
CopyAllUsers=false, CopyAllRoles=false
```

If the database already create, How to add this two property to ProSource click [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398069.aspx)

Hope it can help!

Comment: where is the  auto-create script?  I get that script and run in a sql editor?  I am a mac dude a d I am using dbvisualizer to connect to the DB from a UI.